# Error using yield in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and am trying to learn how yield works. I am using yield in the following way to read characters in a file with help of a function. The return value of this function is input to another function which extracts words based on spaces. However, I am getting the following error while execution:

```
in `block (2 levels) in getchars': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
```

Here is the code snippet generating error:

```
def getchars(file)
    IO.readlines(file).each {|line| line.each_char {|chrc| yield chrc }}
end
```

Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Addition:

This is how I make call:

```
def getwords(file)
  @st_char = true
  getchars(file).each {|c|
    if @st_char == true
        @word = ""
        if c.match(/^[[:alnum:]]+$/)
            @word = c
            @st_char = false
        end
    else
        if c.match(/^[[:alnum:]]+$/)
            @word = @word + c
        else
            @st_char = true
            yield @word
    end
  end
}
end
```

Comment: What are your trying to achieve? Do you want the file as a `string`?

Comment: You don't need a `block` to go about your requirement, so just answered without it. It may help you speed up with your requirement, I advise you can pick up block a little later when you are pretty confident with simpler Ruby concepts.

Comment: remove `.each`  from the getchars.    The yield replaces it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is pretty clear: `getchars` tries to `yield` to a block, but whoever called `getchars` didnt' pass a block.

In line 2 of `getwords`, you call `getchars` without passing a block. You need to pass a block to `getchars`, so it has something to `yield` to.

Comment: Added calling function to make it clear. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a code block to `getchars` for it to yield to.

something like,

```
getchars("example.txt") {|char| puts char}
```

Then inside your get chars, it will yield each char one at a time to the supplied code block - which simply `puts` them out.

Answer (score -1):

```
file_as_string = File.read("greetings.txt") # => "hey hello hola vanakam"
array_of_words_after_splitting_by_spaces = file_as_string.split(" ") # => ["hey", "hello", "hola", "vanakam"]
```

**Warning**: Please don't use such variable names, just used it to explicitly see whats happening

Comment: Wrote it for the sake of his requirements.